# Function template selected instead of specific std::string overload when called with a string literal

Tags: c++, function, templates, overloading

I have the following function template in one of my classes:

```
template<typename T> void Add(T data) { memcpy(cursor, &data, sizeof(T)); }
```

It works, but it is not adapted to `std::string`, for which the correct function would be:

```
void Add(string data) { memcpy(cursor, data.c_str(), data.size()); }
```

Unfortunately if I call the function with a string

```
Add("my text");
```

the function called is the one generated by the template. Is there a way to give my own function priority for specific types? Can I overload the function generated by the template somehow? I've tried some hacky stuff with `std::is_same`, `std::enable_if_t`, and other things but nothing seems to quite work.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted there? An overload which is templated, and an overload which takes a `string`?

Comment: The overload is missing `template <>`?

Comment: Just should provide a specialization for `std::string`.

Comment: If you have an overload for `std::string` but the template is being chosen instead then we will need an [mre] in order to tell you why that isn't working as the non-function template should take precedence over the function template

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow That's specializing, not overloading.

Comment: Also you should be taking a `const string &` or even better a `string_view`.

Comment: the template generate a function for the type `string` as well, so my own function isn't called, it calls the template version which contains a pointer to the actual text but not the text itself.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I don't think there's any indication that `template <>` would be required here.

Comment: @PierreCiholas If you want us to believe that, you'll need to edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: @NathanOliver I know, that was the point.

Comment: The original template should also require that T is trivially copyable and something the `cursor` can accept. That should exclude `std::string` from it as well.

Comment: @PierreCiholas you should take measures to make sure your template function only applies to types for which `std::is_trivially_copyable<T>` is `true`.  `std::string` is by far not the only type that would misbehave if copied via `memcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake, when passing a string directly by doing Add("my text") the type is actually `const char*` overloading the template with a function `void Add(const char*) { ... }` solved the issue.

Comment: How to do that properly is worth a question of its own, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

try to use template partitial specialization:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void Add(T data) { 
  memcpy(cursor, &data, sizeof(T)); 
}

// partitial version
template <>
void Add(std::string data) { 
  memcpy(cursor, data.c_str(), sizeof(T)); 
}
```

Comment: The question was updated, providing additional context which revealed that this was not the right answer :(